# Animating a (pure) flex box menu fly-out., in PicoCSS

Tags: html, css, css-animations, css-frameworks

I made a [responsive CSS-only hamburger menu, designed to be "compatible" with PicoCSS](https://codepen.io/brentarias/pen/gOQybod).  This means that the usual `nav` menu is simply a row-based flexbox, per [PicoCSS documentation](https://picocss.com/docs/navs.html).  My menu works, as the [codepen link](https://codepen.io/brentarias/pen/gOQybod) demonstrates, but it isn't animated.  I attempted an animation, hoping the menu would "grow" vertically, but the animation isn't working at all.

I suspect this is because, to keep the menu simple, I used a media-query to convert the full-screen, row-based menu options into a mobile "column-based, wrapped, max-width: 100%, max-height:fit-content" flex.  That sudden change was probably too much for the animation to sort out.

Regardless, any ideas of how to make this "grow vertically" animation happen?  I definitely want to do this CSS-only (no JavaScript) if at all possible.

If I need a more fundamental "shift" in how I approach this, that's ok, but I still want to remain as close as possible to the original simplicity that PicoCSS was promoting.

Actually, I'd also like to know how to make the links of the "fly-out" menu be selectable anywhere within their boundaries.  As is, I can only select them if I click on the text itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`max-height:fit-content;` is not "transitionable". You need a fixed value.

I'd use something like `max-height:100vh;`

For more info see: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/

Comment: Your answer caused an animation to happen, for the first time!  That said, do you also have an answer of how I can make the entire width of the fly-out menu selectable and hoverable?  Right now, only the menu text is directly selectable / hoverable.

Comment: That would be worthy of  a seperate question. The 2 things are quite unrelated.